# "eject" command not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, compact-disc

```
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~$ eject -v
eject: using default device `cdrom'
eject: device name is `cdrom'
eject: expanded name is `/media/cdrom'
eject: `/media/cdrom' is a link to `/media/cdrom0'
eject: `/media/cdrom0' is not mounted
eject: `/media/cdrom0' is not a mount point
eject: tried to use `/media/cdrom0' as device name but it is no block device
eject: unable to find or open device for: `cdrom'
shadyabhi@shadyabhi-desktop:~$
```

The tray doesnt open.. How do I open tray using command line?

I am using **Ubuntu 9.10 64bit** and I have no dvd inserted in the DVDROM...

Comment: Please post details about the DVD-ROM drive in this computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your device and how it is set up one of those commands should work:

```
eject /dev/cdrom
eject /dev/cdrw
eject /dev/dvd
eject /dev/dvdrom
eject /dev/dvdrw
```

If none of these work then look for the correct device in the list generated by this command:

```
ls -l /dev | grep '\->'
```

You can also specify the raw device:

```
eject /dev/sda
eject /dev/hdd
```

Comment: eject: unable to find or open device for: ******..

For all of them, same errors... And I want to make a point that I dont have any DVD loaded in the DVDROM.

Comment: Do you know to wich device node your drive is bound?

Comment: try this: ls -l /dev | grep '\->' if your dvd device is properly recognized by your system it will be on that list. On my system I get, along with some junk: 'dvd -> hda' and 'cdrw -> hda', eject /dev/dvd, eject /dev/hda, and eject /dev/cdrom all work

Comment: the absence of a dvd in the drive will not affect any of these commands at all

Comment: cdrom2 -> sr0, cdrw2 -> sr0, 
core -> /proc/kcore, 
dvd2 -> sr0, 
dvdrw2 -> sr0... is the output.. I now did "eject /dev/dvd2"... And now it works.. Thanx..

Answer (score 1):

Try `$ eject -t`

Comment: not working.. same error...

Answer (score 1):

Try `eject -T`.

**Edit:**

You may need to name the device or mount point. It may be something other than the ones that it automatically tried. Look at the output of `mount` to see which ones might be it.

Comment: not working. same error

Comment: Actually, I have no DVD inserted, so there isnt anything mounted.. So, what can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I could find to make `eject` to detect cdrom by default (without any options or arguments):

```
echo "/dev/sr0  /media/cdrom0  udf,iso9660 user,noauto  0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mkdir -p /media/cdrom0
cd /media
ln -s cdrom0 cdrom
```

You may have to change `sr0` to `scd0` depending on your system